# how to make sound from database when press button from list

Tags: android, sqlite, button, text-to-speech

In my program I have a list like  [this picture](http://plixi.com/p/75290578#)

so you can see that each list have 2 lines and 1 button so I call each button from each list like this

```
public void buttonGetClicked(View v){
    db.open();
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
    TextView idRow = (TextView) linearLayout.getChildAt(4);
    Toast.makeText(Im_SensShow.this, idRow.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and result is if I click button in list one , it will display "1"
and if I click button in list two, it will display "2"

but the thing that I need is get text from database to read  in TTS function

(for example in [this picture](http://plixi.com/p/75290578#) : if press button in list one ,TTS will make sound like "Do you have a room" and if I press button in list two, TTS will make sound like "Do you")

and I've coded database already like this

```
public Cursor getSound(String rowId) {
    return db.query(IM_SENS_TABLE, new String[] { 
            KEY_IM_SENS_ID,
            KEY_IM_SENS},
            KEY_IM_SENS_ID + "="+ rowId, 
            null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

I try to write like this

```
public void buttonGetClicked(View v){
    db.open();
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
    TextView idRow = (TextView) linearLayout.getChildAt(4);
    Cursor cc = cursor;
    cc = db.getSound(idRow.getText().toString());
    startManagingCursor(cc);
    String sp=cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.KEY_IM_SENS));
    onInit(sp);
 }
    public void onInit(String speech) {
    tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
    tts.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
   }
```

but It force close

please help

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the error from your logcat

Comment: http://plixi.com/p/75664674 this is my error logcat

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is throwing a `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  Initially I suspected `getColumnIndexOrThrow()`, however this should throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the column does not exist.

As such I'm thinking that the error may lie in your `db.getSound()` call.  Check the code in this method to see if anything can throw a `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  You could also either step through the code using a debugger or add some `Log.d()` output to narrow down the cause of the issue.